# Problem after removal of MongoDB

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, 15.10, mongodb

I installed mongoDB using this [instruction manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), but was unable to start it, so I decided to remove the Database by following same instruction set. Since the removal I don't get default options when I type mongo in console what I get is

```
bash: /usr/bin/mongo: No such file or directory
```

I have deleted the public key which was added when I was installing mongo using same Instructions.

Answer (score 0):

When i followed this guide few weeks back - I got rid of the existing mongo-db packages that came with trusty tahr(14.04.3) by using

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

then installed it.

I believe that key is needed during first time install and then for updates not for uninstall(I am guessing).

So essentially

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

You should be able to uninstall it.
If that doesn't work then the only option for clean uninstall is to install it all over again and then uninstall it.